# Jasmine, Parse.com&Promises: Testing functions that call query.get/find

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, promise, automated-tests

I'm trying to get my head around testing a parse.com backed data service, but have not found a satisfying solution so far. Basically, I want to use karma/jasmine to test a function returning a promise.
I'm spying on the query.get() method to intercept and return an object that was created in the implementation of the jasmine spec. However, when the spy returns the local object, the success path of the query.get options argument is not executed. Instead, the to-be-tested function directly returns the unresolved promise, which is not what I want. Basically, I want to test the success path (and the error path) of the data service.

Here's the code:

- to-be-tested parse.com data services

```js
angular.module('app.services',[])
    .factory('AppServices',function(){
      var doFunction1 = function(){
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();
        var ParseObjectClass = Parse.Object.extend('ParseObject');
        var query = new Parse.Query(ParseObjectClass);
        query.get('abc1234',{
          success: function(result){
            promise.resolve(result);
          },
          error: function(result, error){
            promise.reject(error);
          }
        });
        return promise;
      }   

      return {
        function1: doFunction1
      }
    });
```

- jasmine spec

```js
describe('MyServices Tests', function() {
  var AppServices;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app.services');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, AppServices) {
    AppServices = AppServices;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    Parse.initialize("key1", "key2");

    var user = new Parse.User({
      id: 'abc1234',
    });

    var ParseObjectClass = Parse.Object.extend('ParseObject');
    var obj1 = new ParseObjectClass({
      id: 'xyc789'
    });

    spyOn(Parse.Query.prototype, 'get')
      .and.callFake(function(options) {
        return Parse.Promise.as(obj1);
      });
  }));

  it('parseMockTest', function() {
    var result = AppServices.function1(2);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

This is the result from the karma log:

```
LOG: '{"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}'
```

I would have expected that the returned promise is resolved.

Any ideas/hints on how to test functions that return promises?

Comment: Please read about stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Thanks for that input. I understand that I could simply return the promise that query.get() returns. In fact, there is more logic in the original function success path - I removed it for simplicity reason (In the real code, there is some prepping up of the data being returned by query.get, which is why I'm constructing a separate promise object).

Comment: You don't need to construct a separate promise object regardless - read that question again. You can just manipulate it inside the `then`.

Comment: ok. After re-reading the mentioned posted again, I got it. Thank you very much :)